# Access list of active in-memory sessions in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to build an admin page where I can view all active in-memory sessions in an asp.net core application. My searches only turn up information on accessing the current session. How can I access the list from within the admin controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one instance of the application, it is easier. You can create a middleware and store session ids in a Set. Then to get the list, you can just use the elements in the Set. If you have multiple instances of the application, you need to create a common db like Redis, and use their Set features. Don't forget to remove the session ids when the session ends, or perhaps make them expire after a while unless renewed.